# PHP- How to find specific word and change it to the other word

Tags: php

Is it possible to find a specific word from the text file and replace it without actually deleting content of the .txt file in PHP? I have tried the below code and it is just adding onto the text file.

```
<?php

$fileLocation = "$light_txt";

// Opens up the .txt file for writing and replaces any previous content
$fh = fopen($fileLocation, "a") or die("Something went wrong!");

// Write either 1 or 0 depending on request from index.html
$stringToWrite = "$onoroff \n";

// Writes it to the .txt file
fwrite($fh, $stringToWrite);
fclose($fh);
```

It has the following content inside of "light.txt",

```
"L1
 L0 
 F"
```

How can i swap L0 to L1 so the content of light.txt file would be "L0, F"? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Very unclear question. Are you actually after `.str_replace("L1", "L0", $stringToWrite)`?

Comment: So you want to change a file... without changing it ? What do you want ? Return modified text ? Why the call to `fwrite()`, though? And whats with the format of the file ? One has two "L" strings, other has one, there's a "," in there... Please clarify.

Comment: Well, I am quite new in PHP briefly I am doing the project so when the user clicks L1(named) button the text should be written in txt file such as L1 and when the user clicks L0 button the L0 should replace L1.

Comment: So you will be using the text file as a database ? You want to "keep the history" by appending data or would it be ok to replace the contents ? There's an answer already, it might work for you.

Comment: I have tried the below solution but it didn't work. Yes that is right i want to use text file as database i want to take data from text file and send it over to the Arduino. For example, if the below buttons had been pressed.                                                                                L1 
L0 
FAN1 
FAN0                                                                                                                             I want to keep the history of the last button that was pressed, such as, L0 and FAN0.

Comment: What you have *should* work for what you are describing: Append infomation to a file without overwriting anything. Since you are calling `fopen` in append mode, any call to `fwrite` should happen at the end of the file. Try to rework your question on what's exactly the problem.

Comment: Just to make it clear what I want to do I want to use content of text document as a database. They will be few buttons in website Light On, Light Off, Fan on, Fan off I want to keep the history of what the user pressed the last time in each buttonwhich will be in this instance if the user pressed Light On then Light off and Fan off then Fan on so the last state of each button should be written in txt file in this case it should be written in text file Light Off, Fan on

Comment: Do I understand correctly if I assume that you want to append to the end of the file every action taken?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by using the php `file_get_content` function which return the content of a given file as a string

The `test.txt` file contain

> Hi John Doe

```
// Get all the content of the file
$content = file_get_contents('test.txt'); 
// Replace "John Doe" with "Jeanne Doe"
$contentReplace = str_replace('John Doe', 'Jeanne Doe', $content);
// Open the file in writing mode
$file = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
// Replace the content of the `test.txt` by the new content generated
fwrite($file, $contentReplace);
```

The content of the `test.txt` file is now

> Hi Jeanne Doe

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your solution didn’t work. Just to make it clear what I want to do I want to use content of text document as a database. They will be few buttons in website. Such as, Light On, Light Off, Fan on, Fan off if the user pressed Light Off then Light On and Fan On then Fan off I want to keep the history of what the user pressed the last time which will be in this instance Light On and Fan off so this should be written in text file

Comment: I made some changes, can you try